# can you use activerecord to find substring of a field? (quick & dirty keyword finder)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Suppose a database contains a field 'keywords' and sample records include:
"pipe wrench"
"monkey wrench"
"crescent wrench"
"crescent roll"
"monkey bars"

is there a way in activerecord to find the records where the keyword field contains the substring "crescent"?

(It's just a quick and dirty lookup for a quick concept prototype)

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Yeah, just use a LIKE statement in MySQL.

In Rails 2.x:

```
Table.find(:all, :conditions => ['keywords LIKE ?', '%crescent%'])
```

In Rails 3.x:

```
Table.where('keywords LIKE ?', '%crescent%').all
```

Comment: Isn't this vulnerable to sql injection?

Comment: No, Rails auto-escapes the parameter. `where("keyword LIKE '#{query}'")` is vulnerable, but `where("keyword LIKE ?", query)` is not.

Comment: Rails 4 works the same way as Rails 3 w/ regards to this question.

Comment: Awesome! I'm sure I will come back to this answer if the Syntax happens to escape me again. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: To be clear, is it autoescaping or using parameterized queries?. Because autoescaping is dangerous regardless of whats claimed. Theres a long history of the idea failure (notably to unicode substitution exploits) , the most famous being PHPs notorious "magic quotes" dumpster fire (Which was then followed by two separate attempts at explicit escape functions before the whole thing was marked "Thar be dragons!" and people started using parameterized queries.

Comment: Wondering how expensive this query is? I ran it on a large database, and it froze.

Comment: Not that this still has a sql vulnerability. If the input the user provides is '%%%' they're going to get all results unless you manually perform an escaping op

Answer (score 22):

The Postgres database syntax would be:

```
YourModelName.where("yourFieldName like ?", "%" + yourSearchTerm + "%")
```

Answer (score 9):

It all depends on your DB. Is it Postgres? MySQL? MongoDB? Anything else?

With Postgres, you could use something like :

```
Rails 2.x => Model.find(:all, :conditions=>["models.keywords ~= ?", 'crescent'])
Rails 3.x => Model.where("models.keywords ~= ?", 'crescent')
```

You just have to find the right syntax for your DB / Rails / ActiveRecord version.

Comment: Thank you that was also helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. I needed to see if there are keywords passed from conrolled input in the frontend component in the body of any questions in my questions table. Here is how I did it in my controller:

```
   def search
     input = params[:q]
       @questions = Question.all
       search_words = input.split(' ')
       @found_question = [];

       search_words.each do |word|
         @found_question << Question.where("questions.body LIKE ?", "%#{word}%")
     end
   end
```