# Rails: How to find_by a field containing a certain string

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a model named Topic, that has a name as a field.

So say I have a term I'm searching for, apple.

If I do a

```
Topic.find_by_name("apple")
```

I get a record back with the name apple. That's good -- but how do I change find_by_name so that it can find "apple juice" as well as "apple" -- basically, find names that contain the original query or exactly match the original query?

**Edit:**
Thanks for all the response. I guess I should've been a little more clear earlier, but what if I want to find by a variable name (obviously I'm not going to want to find by the name "apple" everytime :) )?

How do I manipulate Topic.where to accommodate for this?
So something like...

```
@topic = Topic.where(......., @name)
```

Comment: Added an edit to my answer related to your latest edit, let me know if that helps!

Comment: See my comment to @Alisher's answer for answer to your edited question.  `Topic.where("name like ?","#{@name}%")` would be one way.

Answer (score 186, accepted):

I think something like this should work:

```
Topic.where("name like ?", "%apple%")
```

To accomodate for your edit:

```
Topic.where("name like ?", "%#{@search}%")
```

Basic string interpolation, you're using the value of `@search` inside the string `%%`, so you `@search = "apple"` then you end up with  `%apple%`

Comment: Do you think this method leads to SQL injection?

Comment: As far as I can tell [here](http://rails-sqli.org/) the `where` method does nothing to protect against SQL injection.  However, the question con only truly be answered by considering if that variable is ever exposed to user input, either through a stored unsanitized value, or directly.  That should be the question of interest.  The best way to counter SQL injection is to sanitize values upon application entry, even before storage.

Comment: how about not contain a certain string?

Comment: Rails prevents SQL injection as long as you use the ? for the argument as shown above.  You'd be left open if you did "name like %@search%" instead.

Comment: @bkunzi01 is right as stated in https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#array-conditions and https://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection

Answer (score 17):

With PostgreSQL you can also use [match operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-TABLE):

```
Topic.where("name ~* ?", @search)
```

Answer (score 12):

Looks like in [Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5044372/can-you-use-activerecord-to-find-substring-of-a-field-quick-dirty-keyword-fi) you would want to use the where:

```
Topic.where("name ILIKE ?", "%apple%")
```

Comment: Not sure if this would work -  is "~=" valid sql?  Or are you thinking of the ruby pattern matcher "=~".  If so it wouldn't work here as it isn't sql

Comment: Yeah I noticed that in the post I referenced and just took it at face value... I will change to LIKE and be safe. Thanks!

Comment: The `~=` operator works for PostgreSQL -- it's a regex match.  But yeah, Scott's answer should work. You might want to use ILIKE, which gives a case-insensitive search.

Answer (score 12):

Don't put string directly like that. Its called SQL injection. You should instead use `.where`:

```
Topic.where("name like '?%' ", params[:name])
```

Comment: Is that supposed to be "name like '?%' " or "name like '%?%' "

Comment: This will not work exactly as noted because Rails will automatically quote the string.  You'll need to tack on the `%` before the substitution, for example `Topic.where("name like ?", "#{params[:name]}%").`

Comment: Beautiful answer. 

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
Topic.where("name like ?",'%apple%')
Topic.find(:all, :conditions => ["name like ?","%apple%"])
```

Comment: SQL injection in first example, should be `Topic.where("name like ?","%apple%")`.  Second one's OK.

Comment: You can also do this in Rails 4+: `Topic.find_by("name like ?", "%apple%")`