# rails 4: array conditions to find substring, the safe/prefered way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to search database by a substring of a field `name`. I found [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708409/rails-how-to-find-by-a-field-containing-a-certain-string) which brings this solution (which works):

```
@users = User.where("name like ?", "%#{params[:name]}%")
```

In [official guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#array-conditions) I found that they recommend to use

```
@users = User.where("name like ?", params[:name])
```

but this has an impact to the result. The recommended code searches for exactly `params[:name]`, the first code finds also strings containing `params[:name]`.

Now I am a little confused

- why is there the difference, it seems to me that the result should be the same,
- what should I then use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is SQL syntax, %string% (first case) will search for substrings. Which to use depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: And how about safety? The official guide considers similar case (with %'s) to be non-recommended, maybe potentially dangerous. Concretely `User.where("name like #{params[:name]}")` is not recomended.

Comment: ("where field is #{something}") is very different from ("where field is ?", something) - the latter is supposedly safe afaik

Answer (score 0):

Using params object it make safe html for futher working instead of pure string
you can see difference just debug it
for example (in location code with the params)

```
raise params.inspect
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to @DeeY's answer.

The `%`s point in the direction of the substrings. So `foo%` translates to

```
search for a match for the string 'foo' and 'foobar' but not 'bazfoo'
```

`%foo%` just means look in both directions from foo.

PostgreSQL also has `ilike` which is a case insensitive search, which is what is needed in most cases. You didn't mention a database but I thought I'd throw that out there.