# rails find records containing specific word

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

I'm looking for a way to find all entries in a database containing a specific string. I know it's possible to iterate over every entry and see if a string matches but with a growing database i'd rather not do that. I'm wondering if there is a Rails way of doing it. 
something like

```
Table.where("content containsWord ?", "string")
```

So a function find all records containing a specific string.
Does anyone know a way to do this?

**update**

duplicate of [Rails: How to find_by a field containing a certain string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708409/rails-how-to-find-by-a-field-containing-a-certain-string)

Comment: @mischa When I written the same thing what RSB has written in my comment then you said it's not working...why so?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try this

```
search_term = "string"
tables = Table.where("tables.content LIKE ?", "%#{search_term}%")
```

**or**, if you want to ignore case sensitiveness, then do this

```
search_term = "string"
tables = Table.where("lower(content) LIKE lower(?)", "%#{search_term}%")
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is what i mean, the only problem i'm still having is that it needs the correct capitalization. I would prefer it if i'm looking for "content" that it also picks records with "Content"

Comment: Check my edited answer, it will work for your case

Comment: @mischa What is the DB engine you are using >