# Search by substring in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

What is the best elegant way to search a substring value in a field like `LIKE` clausure in sql?

> `Person.find_by_name(...)`

Should be equivalent to

> SELECT * FROM people WHERE name LIKE '%FOO%'

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5044372/can-you-use-activerecord-to-find-substring-of-a-field-quick-dirty-keyword-fi) but it's ugly. I'm using Rails 4.

Comment: The answer you suggested says `Table.where('keywords LIKE ?', '%crescent%')`. If you do not want to create your own method, I think it is the best way.

Comment: @Bjoernsen do you know a better what to use active record to find substrings - in rails 5?