# Select records matching subset of integer value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a table named `User` (Created by Devise), and a column `school`, of type string.

Some example values for `school`: `"0"`, `"1"`, `"012"`, `"023"`.

I want to select rows that include `"0"` in the value. Similar to how `#include?` works in Ruby. E.g.:

```
"012".include?("0") == true
"1".include?("0") == false
```

How can I do this with an `ActiveRecord` query?

Comment: If you have integer data type and want to store `012` in it, it would be stored as `12`. Please make sure if `012` and `12` mean same or different to you.

Comment: Please post your user table schema

Comment: Also worth pointing out that the examples are using strings `"012".include?("0") == true`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It is not integer, but string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can you use activerecord to find substring of a field? (quick & dirty keyword finder)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5044372/can-you-use-activerecord-to-find-substring-of-a-field-quick-dirty-keyword-fi)

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your database type (MySQL, PostgreSQL..) but basically you can do the following:

to return all values with '0' somewhere in the string:

```
User.where("school LIKE '%0%'")
```

to return only values with prefix '0':

```
User.where("school LIKE '0%'")
```

Comment: This won't work, considering `school` is not a string according to the poster.

Comment: @Drenmi it should be a string. There is no chance to write `012` "integer" into database :)

Comment: A good idea then is to ask for clarification is a comment. As the question stands, this answer is incorrect. :-) If he actually meant string, it is guaranteed to be a duplicate.

Comment: ofcourse I assume the school value is string... This was before the question was fixed. But I do not know an integer with 0 prefix in base 10 number...

Comment: OP clarified that it is actually `string`. :-)

Comment: so my answer still stands

Answer (score 0):

As @Drenmi states, the database won't store leading zeros in an integer field. If this is a identifier or a phone number where the leading zero has significance you will need to store the data in another field type.

Use a string field to store the numbers. You'll then be able to use a `LIKE` query to get what you want. In that case the following is one way to do that.

You can use arel and the `matches` method. See [How to do a LIKE query in Arel and Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430578/how-to-do-a-like-query-in-arel-and-rails)

So:

to return all values with '0' somewhere in the string:

```
users = User.arel_table
User.where(users[:school].matches('%0%'))
```

to return only values with prefix '0':

```
users = User.arel_table
User.where(users[:school].matches('0%')
```

Comment: This won't work, considering `school` is not a string according to the poster.

Comment: That will teach me for not reading the question more carefully. I'll modify my answer to suit. Thank you @Drenmi

Comment: It is very possible that the poster made a mistake though, as I don't think you can store leading zeroes in integer fields. :-)

Comment: @Drenmi I'm sure you are right. If they want to test for the presence of the zero, they'll need it to be present. I think I've updated my post to cover that.

Comment: OP clarified that it is actually `string`. :-)